# как понять предложение

Tags: союзы

Требуется высшее  (бакалавриат, специалитет) или среднее профессиональное образование либо профессиональная переподготовка в соответствии с профилем деятельности.
Относится ли фраза "в соответствии с профилем деятельности" и к высшему, и к среднему профессиональному образованию? Или это требование лишь для профессиональной подготовки? Разошлись во мнении, объясните пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В логике этого высказывания ровно две альтернативы, разделённых взаимоисключающим "**либо**": а) требуется образование одного из двух упомянутых видов и б) при отсутствии (а) требуется *переподготовка в соответствии с профилем (предполагаемой) деятельности.*

Такое требование логично, если на какую-то должность ищут человека либо с дипломом, либо прошедшего иную подготовку (курсы и т.п.), достаточную для работы в данной должности. Однако, если составитель этого хотел отнести "профиль деятельности" и к диплому тоже, то это не удалось; для такого указания нужно было поместить упоминание о "профиле" в начало предложения, что логически объединило бы его с общим для двух альтернатив "требованием".

Answer (score 0):

Фраза "в соответствии с профилем деятельности" может относится и к высшему, и к среднему профессиональному образованию. Поскольку профессиональную переподготовку может пройти специалист как со среднем профессиональным образованием, так и специалист с высшим профессиональным образованием.

Comment: но меня интересует не кто может пройти переподготовку, а обязательно ли человеку иметь высшее образование "в соответствии с профилем деятельности", или он может иметь любое образование, а профиль - это только про проф переподготовку имеется ввиду?

Comment: @Регина : В силу того, что у Вас там "либо", то "профессиональная переподготовка" *не относится* ни к тому, ни к другому.

Comment: Большое спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Регина, все спорящие стороны правы и неправы одновременно.
Правы, когда дают свое толкование, а неправы в том, что вообще спорят, ибо не о чем.

В целом же по опыту, совсем не филологического плана, я считаю, что здесь имеется в виду **любое высшее / среднее специальное", хотя не имею абсолютных к тому доводов.

Попробуем по порядку.

Грамматика русского языка позволяет двояко трактовать эту фразу. У союза "или" нет никаких преимуществ перед союзом "либо" (в подобном значении), поэтому нет никаких оснований считать, что союз "либо" ограничивает сферу влияния оборота "в соответствии ...". К тому же нет никаких оснований считать, что канцелярист, писавший фразу, руководствовался чем-то, кроме своего собственного понимания.

Здесь для толкования нужны не филологи, а кадровики, которые знают реально, что требуется для данной вакансии. Я же могу только рекомендовать не употреблять подобных двусмысленных конструкций.

С другой стороны, понятно, что *профессиональная переподготовка* в данной конструкции не может не быть направленной - в соответствии с требованиям к вакансии, а вот про высшее и среднее - не очевидно... По установленным еще советскими кадровиками "умолчанию" такая формулировка предполагает любое высшее / средне специальное, иначе бы написали "профильное высшее..." и т.п.

Чисто же практически вопрос решается очень просто. Потенциальный соискатель вакансии должен трактовать так, как ему удобнее, иначе он рискует упустить вакансию по недоразумению. Так что я на его месте со всех точек зрения не распространял бы действие "соответствия" на высшее и среднее, а отправил бы резюме - и пусть кадровик разбирается.

Что касается мнения Сержа, то оно, конечно, имеет право на существование, но я бы почти наверняка для передачи подобной мысли построил бы фразу иначе:

*Требуется высшее (бакалавриат, специалитет) или среднее профессиональное образование в соответствии с профилем деятельности, либо профессиональная переподготовка.*

Таким образом по косвенным соображением еще раз убеждаемся в том, что "высшее или среднее специальное" тут понимается **любое**.